# A function to take elements from an array and make a new array out of them

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I have to create a function which takes 3 arguments, an array and two numbers, the second and third arguments are representing indexes,I need to take the elements in the array that are at the given indexes and push them to a new array.And then return this new array.

```
//======================  EXAMPLE  ========================
var arr = [
  "Breaking bad",
  "WestWorld",
  "Psych",
  "Games of Thrones",
  "Gotham",
  "Spartacus",
  "Dexter",
  "Office"
];
take_and_push(arr, 2, 4)
["Psych", "Gotham"]; // <======  EXPECTED OUTPUT
//=========================================================
```

And then I wrote this function:

```
function take_and_push(array, num1, num2){
  var array1 = new Array(1);
  array1.push(array[num1], array[num2]);
}
```

But it returns just undefined.

Comment: for a function to return something you have to `return something`

Comment: right! LOL, I didn't take advantage of this post, now I have to wait 90 min for mi next problem. Hahaha Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code.

```
function take_and_push(array, num1, num2){
  var array1 = [];
  array1.push(array[num1], array[num2]);
  return array1; //or console.log(array1);
}
```